# Unity: доступ к вложенному классу из другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток. В игре есть класс GameScore, в котором есть некоторое кол-во вложенных классов, которые должны хранить данные для сравнений. 
Вот сам класс:

```
public class GameScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    //first level info
    public class FirstLevel
    {
        internal const float HightScore = 7f;
        internal const float MiddleScore = 11f;
        internal const float LowScore = 15f;

        internal static int bestResult = 0;
    }

    //second level info
    public  class SecondLevel
    {
        internal const float HightScore = 5f;
        internal const float MiddleScore = 7f;
        internal const float LowScore = 9f;

        internal static int bestResult = 0;
    }
}
```

А теперь сам вопрос: как мне из другого класса получить доступ к вложенному классу `FirstLevel`, например?

P.S. Я пытаюсь добавить к другому классу public переменную `GameScore` и уже оттуда получить доступ к вложенному классу, но ничего не получается.

**Update** (как я пытаюсь получить доступ к классу FirstLevel):

```
public GameScore GameScorePrefab;
private void CheckStars()
    {
        int bestResult = GameScorePrefab.FirstLevel.bestResult;
        //другой код
    }
```

После этого пишет: "GameScore.FirstLevel is a type, which is not valid in the given context.FirstLevel cannot reference a type through an expresion, try GameScore.FirstLevel instead." А интелесенс класс FirstLevel вообще не видит.

Comment: Как именно не получается? И что именно не получается? Что пишет? Покажи сам как пишешь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский апдейтнул вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте сделал `public` переменные в `GameScore` и обращался через них. И возможно вместо `internal` использование `public`, поскольку вы возможно пытаетесь обращаться из другого `namespace`

```
public class GameScore : MonoBehaviour
{

public FirstLevel firstLevel;
public SecondLevel secondLevel;
//first level info
public class FirstLevel
{
    internal const float HightScore = 7f;
    internal const float MiddleScore = 11f;
    internal const float LowScore = 15f;

    public /*static*/ int bestResult = 0;
}

//second level info
public  class SecondLevel
{
    internal const float HightScore = 5f;
    internal const float MiddleScore = 7f;
    internal const float LowScore = 9f;

    public /*static*/ int bestResult = 0;
}


}
```

тогда доступ будет следующим образом:

```
public GameScore GameScorePrefab;
private void CheckStars()
{
    int bestResult = GameScorePrefab.firstLevel.bestResult;
    //другой код
}
```

Comment: `public FirstLevel firstLevel = new FirstLevel();`

Comment: Что-то я не понял смысла этих переменных публичных. Если в итоге чтобы их объявить также придется через точку через основной класс обращаться. что так писать `public GameScore GameScore;  GameScore = new GameScore();
     GameScore.firstLevel = new GameScore.FirstLevel();`  что так: `GameScore.FirstLevel firstLevel = new GameScore.FirstLevel();` - как бэ я не понял выигрыш состоит в чем))

Comment: ну я так понял что человеку нужны экземпляры а не статика как написано изначально, значит делаем экземпляры. А то что смысла во вложенных классах нет, это да

Answer (score 1):

Если вложенный тип нужно применять вне включающего типа, его надо квалифицировать именем включа­ющего типа.

То есть если имеется класс:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public class PublicInnerClass {}
    private class PrivatelnnerClass {}
}
```

то обращение должно быть таким:

```
void MyMethod() {
    // Создать и использовать открытый вложенный класс.
    OuterClass.PublicInnerClass inner;
    inner = new OuterClass.PublicInnerClass();    
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - полное имя
}
```

или

```
OuterClass.PublicInnerClass inner;

void MyMethod() {
    inner = new OuterClass.PublicInnerClass();    
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - полное имя
}
```

и т.д.

---

Если хочешь сохранять данные по каждому лвл, то почему бы не использовать какой-нибудь словарь, где ключом будет номер лвл? Да или просто в список добавлять. А этот список хранить в `asset`, к примеру.

Comment: Либо так, да. Сама идея, конечно,  у меня не очень рациональна.

Comment: @Pepsi4 а я так и не понял её)) Почему в обоих внутренних классах стоят значения разные? К чему они относятся? Если туда для каждого уровня для каждого игрока будут сохраняться данные, то смысла в кучи этих внутренних классов нет. достаточно одного. который будет храниться в списке и добавляться туда, как я уже писал. А если нет - то я ничего не понимаю что это) ................... и тем более если уровней будет не один и два а 10-20 то даже решение KingPeas не спасет. будет как сильный костыль выглядеть..хотя я не понял смысла его манипуляций. Они такие же как у меня в ответе в итоге О_о

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в код:

```
using static YourNamespace.GameScore;
```

и используйте:

```
int bestResult = FirstLevel.bestResult;
```

или через имя "внешнего" класса:

```
int bestResult = GameScore.FirstLevel.bestResult;
```

Comment: Увы, но добавлять в юзинг статик неймспейсы можно только с 6-ой версии c#, На Unity версии 5.5 у меня сейчас стоит c# 4.0.